# After upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 radeon driver not being used?

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

Upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04.3 to 16.04.1 with Xmonad window manager.

Output of `lspci  -mm | grep VGA` is:

```
00:01.0 "VGA compatible controller" "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]" "Richland [Radeon HD 8650G]" "Hewlett-Packard Company" "Richland [Radeon HD 8650G]"
```

Output of `sudo lshw -C video` is

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Richland [Radeon HD 8650G]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:5000(size=256) memory:f0400000-f043ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0300000-f033ffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:f0340000-f035ffff
```

Output of `lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3` is

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Richland [Radeon HD 8650G] [1002:990b]
    DeviceName: RICHLAND (990B)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Richland [Radeon HD 8650G] [103c:1985]
    Kernel modules: radeon
```

I upgraded to 16.04.1 recently, understanding that fglrx would be removed and that a free graphics driver would be installed instead.  In 14.04 I was running the proprietary driver for the Intel part of the hybrid card.  After upgrading there are a few strange graphics behaviours.  Some icons appear very large while others are normal.  The laptop also runs about fifteen degC hotter.

I looked at the proprietary driver tab ubuntu-control-center.  It seems that after the update the system still thought I was using fglrx.  I installed the radeon driver and switched to it.  When I rebooted and checked again, there was no proprietary graphics driver listed and the command outputs are now as above.

Am I right in understanding that though the radeon kernel module is loaded it is not being used?  If so, what must I do to use it?

Comment: It is used. You can see it by `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display'`

Comment: Yes the driver is loaded, and no it's not being used actively.  I also have a hybrid card, and the Intel card was always used not matter what I did to try to switch it with vgaswitcheroo.  16.04 doesn't have support for proprietary drivers and so far, it never will.  My fix for this was to downgrade to 14.04 and it works as it should.  Not a solution for 16.04, but I'm personally not missing out on anything by running 14.04.

Comment: @Dorian how easy/difficult was it to downgrade?  I think that is probably the best route for the next three years, but I'm trying to avoid a reinstall from scratch.

Comment: @TonyMartin unfortunately, downgrading isn't as easy as upgrading.  I basically made a backup of all my files in /home, reinstalled from scratch and then restored my files.  Then it was just a matter of reinstalling the programs I use.  It's definitely worth it in the end, especially when you're good to go for 3 years.  Also, with the hybrid cards, you get overheating in 16.04 because the AMD card is always on.  In 14.04, it turns the card off when not in use, and my laptop runs much cooler.

Comment: @Dorian which leads to the answer below...

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** At the moment if you have a hybrid AMD graphics that is not specifically identified as compatible with the latest amdgpu driver, you would do well to steer clear of 16.04 for the foreseeable future.

**Reason:** Although the open radeon driver can be installed, it will not be used and you will not be able to shutdown the high performance graphics hardware.  This makes for a very hot and noisy machine and a degradation of graphics performance compared to fglrx on 14.04

**The good news:** Whilst installing 14.04 back in May 2014 was immensely difficult, due to poor support for the AMD graphics adapter, and merely very difficult back in November 2015, it was very straightforward installing 14.04.4 yesterday as all necessary drivers were made available and run reliably straight out of the pack.  Perhaps by April 2018 16.06.4 will have reliable drivers for older AMD devices.  In the meantime, if I need a new machine, I'll be looking for Nvidia.  YMMV.